# Altering PySide.QtGui.QListWidget with an emitted signal from a multiprocessing.Pool async call results in Runtime Error?

Tags: python, pyside, python-multithreading, qlistwidget

I have:

```
from PySide.QtCore import Signal, QObject
from multiprocessing import Pool

def some_computation():
    pass
    # ..some computations
    return 'result'

class MyClass(QObject):

    my_signal = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        self.mylistwidget = # ... QListWidget from somewhere

        # bind the signal to my slot
        self.my_signal.connect(self.on_my_signal)

    # this is called after computation thread is finished
    def my_callback_fct(result):
        # ..bla bla
        self.my_signal.emit()

    # this is the function I call
    def do_some_async_computation(self)
        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        pool.apply_async(target=some_computation, callback=my_callback_fct)

    # this is the slot
    def on_my_signal(self):
        self.mylistwidget.clear()
```

I read around stackoverflow that in order to change the gui from a secondary execution thread one must use slot-signal mechanism, which is what I did in **MyClass**, although when I call **do_some_async_computation** I would expect the pool to initiate a secondary thread for **some_computation** function ..which happens, after the computation is finished the **my_callback_fct** is executed accordingly, which emits a **my_signal** signal that is connected to the **on_my_signal** slot, which is executed as expected, but when altering the self.mylistwidget it gives a `Runtime Error` / `QWidget runtime error redundant repaint detected`

Comment: I think you're going to have to include enough code here to reproduce the issue. If I create my own example program using just what you've provided, the `mylistwidget.clear()` call actually works fine.

Comment: How is the Result-object apply_async returns being treated? In the code above, the my_callback_fct would have never been called.

Comment: @deets `my_callback_fct` gets called automatically when `some_computation` completes (as long as it doesn't throw an exception).

Comment: @dano I doubt that. The apply_async call returns an -AsyncResult-object. On this, you need to call wait, get or other methods. And only then the the callback could be invoked. Think of it as this: issue a async_callback disregarding the returned value (as the OP does). Then you enter a while True: pass loop. Where would the timeslice for executing the callback come from? It would require a magically spun-up Thread, and even that would need the AsyncResult. So - there is something missing to this story.

Comment: @deets Try it for yourself. The function provided as the `callback` keyword argument gets executed as soon as as the function provided to `apply_async` completes. You don't need to call `get` on the `AsyncResult` object. The callback is executed in a background that that is started by the `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Comment: @deets And the result handling thread has access to the `AsyncResult` object, because a handle for the correct `AsyncResult` is included in the payload returned from each worker process, via a `multiprocessing.Queue`. The result handling thread consumes from that `Queue`, and can that grab the `AsyncResult` from a cache that holds a reference to all active `AsyncResult` instances. The `callback` function is stored in the `AsyncResult`, so it just executes it using the result it pulls out of the `Queue`.

Comment: @dano I stand corrected - I just did try it out. And there *is* in fact a magic thread being invoked in the background. To be honest, I find this a bit concerning, that there is no mentioning of this in the documentation. Oh well. Then I guess I try & answer the OP's question :) And thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: @deets `multiprocessing.Pool` actually starts 2-3 threads (depending on Python version) in the background. `multiprocessing.Queue` starts one, too. The only mention of threads being used with `Pool` objects in the docs is actually referencing the `callback` keyword argument: *"callback should complete immediately since otherwise **the thread which handles the results will get blocked**."*. I agree it should probably be stated more clearly, since it has implications on what `callback` can do, and also on how things will behave if you `fork`.

Comment: do you guys think this is the best approach regarding how to handle separation between GUI thread and some other heavy computation thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a `QtCore.QThread` instead of `multiprocessing.Pool`. I was thinking about the mechanism you talked about @deets and I said to myself that it should be in in the same context in order for `Qt.QueuedConnection` to work, so that's why I wanted to go with **QThread**.

```
class MyComputationalThread(PySide.QtCore.QThread):

    data_available = PySide.QtCore.Signal(str)
    def run(self):
        result = # ... do computations
        serialized_result = json.dumps(result) #  actually I use JSONEncoder here
        self.data_available.emit(serialized_result)
```

... and in my `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass(QObject):
    # ...
    mythread = MyComputationalThread()
    # ...

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.mythread.connect(do_something_with_serialized_data, PySide.QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        # ...
```

It works like a charm.

Comment: @andrew-g-h *facepalm* Jup. You of course need a QThread. I even said it myself, but didn't connect the dots...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't observed your actual error, but in a similar scenario we use a QueuedConnection to ensure the signal is passed correctly from one thread to the other. This is done automagically for some people if the objects in question belong to different threads (QObject have a notion of the QThread that owns them). But in your case, all is done on one object, so Qt can't know. Do

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
...
self.my_signal.connect(self.on_my_signal, Qt.QueuedConnection)
```

Comment: Nope, still crashes. I've added part of my original code.